# jvm full gc can't unload classes even permgen is full

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, weblogic, permgen, java-memory-leaks

Our production server went OOM because permgen is full. Using `jmap -permstat` to check the permgen area, we found there were many classes loaded by `com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSSServiceDelegatingLoader`. The loaded classes are `com.sun.proxy.$ProxyXXX`, where `XXX` is an int sequence.
[image]

the stacktrace for these classloading is as follow:
[image]

eventually, the JVM went OOM, full gc can't reclaim any permgen memory.
What is strange is that if I click System GC in VisualVM, the classes are unloaded and the usage of permgen goes down.
[image]

Our JDK version is 1.7.0.80， we have added `CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`.

```
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent

-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60

-XX:+UseParNewGC

-XX:+CMSParalledlRemarkEnabled

-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection

-XX:+CMSFullGCsBeforeCompaction=0

-XX:+CMSCLassUnloadingEnabled

-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=18

-XX:+UseCMSInitialtingOccupancyOnly

-XX:SurvivorRatio=4

-XX:ParallecGCThreads=16
```

Our code has been running for a long time. The most recent operation is a WebLogic patch. This really confused me. Could someone give me some help with this issue, many thanks!

Comment: I’m assuming that the typos in `-XX:ParallelcGCThreads` is a copy and paste error in this question?

Comment: yes. The original picture has waterprint, so I type thes options by hand

Comment: @XinliNiu this is surprising that Full GC was not able to collect dead classloaders but same is getting cleaned by force GC. Can you please share the GC logs?

Comment: Maybe the code that runs into the OutOfMemoryError is actively using code loader by that class loader. So only clicking “GC” in VisualVM when that code is not on the stack can reclaim the class loader.

Comment: Our security department attached an agent by instrumentation, which starts a thread and scans all the loaded classes, so they cant be reclaimed. They didn't inform me and started the scan at random time. When I click "system gc" in visualvm, the agent isn't attached, so the class can be unloaded, which misleads me. Our app does hava the jax-ws bug which creates a new proxy on every getPotr() call, but the class can be unloaded normally.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug https://github.com/javaee/metro-jax-ws/issues/1161

Every time a JAX-WS client is created, for instance, using library JAX-WS RI 2.2 which is bundled in Weblogic Server 12.1.3

```
com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate$DelegatingLoader#1
```

Client proxy classes are being loaded into classloader:

```
([Loaded com.sun.proxy.$Proxy979 from com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate$DelegatingLoader] )
```

**Solution/Workaround:**
Replace JAX-WS client where this bug is solved.